# Can't call python library when calling python from MATLAB Compiler application

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to run python scripts from a MATLAB compiled application (Using MATLAB Compiler) and for some weird reason it can't find any import from scipy. When I try to call any scipy method it gives me this error

```
Python Error: ImportError: cannot import name sigtools
```

If I call the same code from Python or MATLAB directly, it works. But not from MATLAB Compiler.

Another weird thing is that the python path that the python call from MATLAB sees is correct, so what could cause this?

**EDIT**
My python path

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
```

I have the file `sigtools.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/
```

Comment: not enough information.  Where is sigtools, what is you `sys.path`, have you even installed sigtools, etc, etc.

Comment: I have this file sigtools.x86_64-linux-gnu.so in my /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/ directory, so I'm assuming that it is installed. Another information is that if I call the same code from python directly it works, the same if I call from directly from MATLAB, not the MATLAB compiler version of it. Thanks for your help

Comment: If it is where you claim it is, then it's obvious `sys.path` wouldn't find it. But `import scipy.signal.sigtools` should work.

Comment: I presume your in Linux, can you able to located the sigtools.so lib in your Linux host?

Comment: It gave me this beautiful error Python Error: ImportError: cannot import name sigtools =(, there's anyway to directly give it the path to my sigtools.so?

Comment: go directly to your path and do this `python -c "import sigtools"`

Comment: Yes, I can locate it. it also works perfectly outside the matlab code.

Comment: When I go to the directory and run python -c "import sigtools" I see no error. So I assume it works... right??

Comment: I've edited your question to add the information that it doesn't work from the compiler version only and as such added some relevant tags. Feel free to rollback or further edit it if I have misrepresented what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, it looks better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem.
The version of `libstdc++` provided by MATLAB runtime environment is too old for importing some python libraries. It should `libstdc++.so.6 version 3.4.21`. I've replaced the file libstdc++.so.6 with an updated version (3.4.21) in `v901/sys/os/glnxa64/` which is the MATLAB runtime directory.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question.

Go directly to the location of where `sigtools.so` lib is located in your machine and do `python -c "import sigtools"` and then in your file, you can import it.

Comment: Can you explain why this should work? All you're doing is importing the file to create the .pyc file. This can be done from any directory and besides, the code has been stated to work for Python and Matlab directly, so I can't see how that would resolve the problem.

Comment: this do not work from MATLAB, I said it works, but when I use python only, from matlab side it gives me Python Error: ImportError: cannot import name sigtools. It seems that MATLAB messes up something in the python path when It starts its python calls.

Comment: Checking in the MATLAB run-time directory (required to run executable without MATLAB), I've found some python files and one called my attention. It seems to be python code that queries python for the information necessary to initialize an embedded interpreter. inside it, there's a class called LibraryFinder, maybe there's a bug in it.